# Is there a way I can convert datatime into high frequency data form?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I tried to convert 91504000 into 09:15:04.000 and I appended 0 to 91504000 into 091504000.
I used this function:

```py
df['MDTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['MDTime'], format='%H:%M:%S,%f')
```

But it does not work.

```
time data '091504000' does not match format '%H:%M:%S' (match)
```

I used this function: df['MDTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['MDTime'], format='%H:%M:%S,%f')

Answer (score 0):

The format variable of pd.to_datetime specifies the **input** format of the function, not the output. Remove the colon characters from your format string and you should see success.